# How to reuse code from the main bin in another bin?

Tags: import, rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

My project structure looks like this:

```
.
├── Cargo.lock
├── Cargo.toml
└── src
    ├── bin
    │   └── other.rs
    ├── main.rs
    └── util.rs
```

(code: https://gitlab.com/msrd0/cargo-bin-import)

In my `other.rs`, I'm trying to reuse code from the `util` mod, which is declared as a public mod in my `main.rs` file. I tried the following:

- `use util::do_sth`
- `use crate::util::do_sth`
- `use cargo_bin_import::util::do_sth` (with and without extern crate)
- `mod util; use util::do_sth`
- `extern crate util; use util::do_sth` (suggested by rustc)

None of the above worked and gave me error messages similar to this one:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `crate::util`
 --> src/bin/other.rs:1:12
  |
1 | use crate::util::do_sth;
  |            ^^^^ maybe a missing `extern crate util;`?

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a library and two binaries, then reuse the lib's code in the two binaries. Example:

Cargo.toml

```
[lib]
name = "utils"
path = "src/utils.rs"

# cargo build --bin other
[[bin]]
name = "other"
path = "src/bin/other.rs"

# cargo build --bin main
[[bin]]
name = "main"
path = "src/main.rs"
```

Then `use utils::{...}`. The path are taken from your question, but putting main inside bin/ and renaming utils.rs to lib.rs could be a more standard way to do it.

If the library is generic enough, you could even release it on crates.io for others to benefit from it.